# Importing multiple project folders in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, module

I have a project opened in Intellij. I want to open one more project inside the same IntelliJ so that both projects appear like a folder `A` and a folder `B`
The new project that I want to import is the `B`
I did the following `File-> Module from existing sources` and selected project B. There are some folders inside Project B. Not all sub-folders that are inside B appear in the IntelliJ. Also, 4 sub-folders inside B appear along with the folder of project A.
`What I wanted is just folder A and folder B is present`.
`But what's happening is that instead of folder B few subfolders are only getting listed inside Intellij`
Probably the IntelliJ is only picking up sub-modules inside B.
Is there a way to load the complete folder A along with folder B in Intellij?

**Things I tried:**
Opened project B in a separate window. Surprisingly it also opens up as 4 subfolders:
Whereas if I go to the project from explorer it has more top-level folders like `resources` not sure why it's not picking those up

[image]

IntelliJ showed up a pop up - `load project as gradle..`  I clicked on it and now only the top-level single folder called `people` is appearing and all the subfolders even the `resources` appear underneath it. So it's working fine if I open it separately
[image]

Comment: Please add some screenshots from projext explorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, IntelliJ **does not support multiple projects open in the same window**.

I believe you've gone down the right road in importing the project as a module. Without seeing what you're describing, I don't know exactly why your folders are appearing as they are but it may be that you need to convert your sources in 'project A' into a module - named, for example, 'module A' first (meaning 'project A' will become its own project with a single module - 'module A' under it).

Then import 'project B' as a module - named, for example, 'module B' - into 'project A'.

So you'd end up now, with a hierarchy like:

```
   {"project A": [
    "module A", 
    "module B"]}
```

(I made up the JSON-like notation for illustrative purposes, I don't think you'll find it anywhere).

In case it helps clarify, you could equally convert `'Project B' into a module ('module B') first, import 'Project A' into it as 'module A'.` The resulting project would have identical contents except the hierarchy would be:

```
{"project B": [
 "module A", 
 "module B"]}.
```

In other words, which project you decide will become your 'main working project' doesn't matter. I'm not 100% sure but I think you can even keep working on each one separately (as in, open in its own IntelliJ window) since all you're doing when creating a module is telling the IDE where the code is via the IML file which I think keeps track of the modules.

If you try this and your files and folder structure still don't seem to make sense, share more detail and I'll try to re-create your issue.

For projects with many modules, I gather you can also sub-group modules though I don't have any experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

If the projects are related i.e. they depend on each other and you're using gradle, you may use the includeBuild feature at which point IJ will open both projects in one view

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Gradle Projects it would be best to manage them through the [Gradle Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/jetgradle-tool-window.html)

Try doing it this way: open Project A, in Gradle Tool Window click "+" icon, navigate to the Project B's folder and click OK.

That should allow you to have both Projects opened in IDEA at the same time.

If you later want to "unlink" the Projects select Project B in the Gradle Tool Window and click "-".